# Javascript / Node.js return wrong Value append String not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Main(){
    var listdata = "";
    var publiclist_temp1 = "============================HELLO-WORLD-START============================";
    listdata + listdata + publiclist_temp1 + "\n";
    listdata = listdata + "Hello World" + '\n';
    listdata = listdata + "Im the King" + "\n";
    var publiclist_temp2 = "============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================";
    listdata = listdata + publiclist_temp2 + "\n";
    return listdata;
}

console.log(Main());
```

**Display Output:**

> Hello World

> Im the King

> ============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================

**Error**: *First string dosnt append whats wrong here?*

Comment: `listdata = listdata + publiclist_temp1 + "\n";` or simply `listdata += publiclist_temp1 + "\n";` (on line four of your provided code). `+` will not mutate (change) the original value/variable.

Comment: Thanks mate, wow crazy

Comment: You could also use backticks and avoid all the hassle ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

You're using `+` instead of `+=`, try this :

```js
function Main(){
    var listdata = "============================HELLO-WORLD-START============================\n";
    listdata += "Hello World" + '\n';
    listdata += "Im the King" + "\n";
    listdata +=  "============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================\n";
    return listdata;
}

console.log(Main());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways (maybe more) to do this.

- Using your string concatination `Main()`
- Using a `+=` `MainPlus()` re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment
- And using a template literal `MainTemplate()`
  re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
function Main() {
  var listdata = "";
  var publiclist_temp1 = "============================HELLO-WORLD-START============================";
  listdata = listdata + publiclist_temp1 + "\n";
  listdata = listdata + "Hello World" + '\n';
  listdata = listdata + "Im the King" + "\n";
  var publiclist_temp2 = "============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================";
  listdata = listdata + publiclist_temp2 + "\n";
  return listdata;
}

function MainPlus() {
  var listdata = "";
  listdata += "============================HELLO-WORLD-START============================";
  listdata += "\n";
  listdata += "Hello World" + '\n';
  listdata += "Im the King" + "\n";
  listdata += "============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================";
  listdata += "\n";
  return listdata;
}

function MainLiteral() {
  let templateLiteral = `============================HELLO-WORLD-START============================
Hello World
Im the king
============================HELLO-WORLD-END============================`;
  return templateLiteral;
}

console.log(Main());
console.log(MainPlus());
console.log(MainLiteral());
```